# EXCEL - put duplicate values from different columns in same row

Tags: excel

I have the following two columns A and B:

[image]

I want to put the duplicated values in same row, and the result would be like:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: what if there is a value is column b that isnt in column a?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Saif. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the formulas (not sure if that is possible) or VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Formulas would require the use of helper columns, or it would need to be VBA.

Comment: put in C2 `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),A2,"")` and copy down... or if you like it different `=IFERROR(LEFT(MATCH(A2,B:B,0),0)&A2,"")` :P

Comment: Thanks dirk you are the best